# How to change default duplicity archive directory?

Tags: backup, directory, archive, duplicity, options

How can I change the duplicity default archive directory (~/.cache/)? The following option seems to be ignored.

**Option** *--archive-dir=/volume4/duplicity/cache/ --name backup*

```
duplicity 0.6.21 (January 23, 2013)
Linux 3.2.40 #4458 SMP Thu Mar 6 14:16:00 CST 2014
/usr/bin/python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 13:32:18)
[GCC 4.6.4 20120731 (prerelease)]
```

**Duplicity Args**

```
Args: /opt/bin/duplicity --no-encryption --verbosity=5 --archive-dir=/volume4/duplicity/cache/ --name backup --tempdir /volume4/tmp/ --full-if-older-than 14D --volsize 100 /volume1/data file:///volume3/backup
```

Duplicity use the default cache directory instead the defined *--archive-dir*

```
Connecting with backend: LocalBackend
Archive dir: /root/.cache/duplicity/fb29be0e131386b16ed08d63a092fcc4
```

Duplicity use *--archive-dir* for temp files only, but not as local archive directory.

```
Using temporary directory /volume4/duplicity/cache/backup/duplicity-6b4wDx-tempdir
Deleting /volume4/duplicity/cache/backup/duplicity-inc.20140317T222627Z.to.20140317T222916Z.manifest
```

Which option should be used to change the archive directory?

Answer (score 3):

You are actually using the right option, but duplicity will ignore it due to the equals sign =.

So rather than using

```
--archive-dir=/volume4/duplicity/cache/ --name backup
```

you must use:

```
--archive-dir /volume4/duplicity/cache/ --name backup
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, using systemrescuecd, which is a livecd.

I had to symlink /root/.cache/duplicity to a tempdir on a mounted harddrive as a solution.